# Music Player Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I created a song player that has a basic functions like play, pause, next etc. When I click play button, the current song Index will play. Now, while the song is playing and I press the back button go to my home activity using intent, the song is still playing. But when I click on the player button to go to the player, the state of my play/pause button is on play and when I click the play button, the default index of my song `(currentSongIndex(1))` index will play and the last song I played is still playing. So therefore, There are 2 song are playing at the same time. How do I solve this?

I want to create a music player that runs on the background even if I exit the app.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Here`s the code.
    package com.hirou.player;

```
public class HirouMusic extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songAlbum;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
private Button details;
private ImageView songAlbumArt;
private ProgressDialog details_dialog;
// Media Player
private  MediaPlayer mp;


// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 20000; // 20000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 20000; // 20000 milliseconds
public int currentSongIndex = 0; 
public int currentSongIndexResume;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.player);


// All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songAlbum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songAlbum);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
    details =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDetails);
    songAlbumArt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.songAlbumArt);




        mp = new MediaPlayer();

    //Getting songs from SongsManager Class stored in arrayList
        songManager = new SongsManager();

        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList(this);

        // By default play first song
        //playSong(0);




        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){

                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();

                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    IS_PLAYING=false;
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position                
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else{
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });


        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position                
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Next button click event
         * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
         * */
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(isShuffle){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                    playSong(currentSongIndex);
                }
                else{
                            // check if next song is there or not
                        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                        }else{
                            // play first song
                            playSong(0);
                            currentSongIndex = 0;
                            }   
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event
         * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                }else{
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Repeat button
         * Enables repeat flag to true
         * */
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }   
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Shuffle button
         * Enables shuffle flag to true
         * */
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isShuffle){
                    isShuffle = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isShuffle= true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isRepeat = false;
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }   
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event
         * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);         
            }
        });

        //---------- Details Button ----------------------------
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private ProgressDialog details_dialog;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String songTitle = songsList.get(currentSongIndex).get("songTitle");
                String songArtist = songsList.get(currentSongIndex).get("songArtist");
                String songDuration = songsList.get(currentSongIndex).get("songDuration");
                String songPath = songsList.get(currentSongIndex).get("songPath");

                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Showing Dialog");
                this.details_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HirouMusic.this, "", "Title : " +songTitle +"\n"
                        + "Artist : " +songArtist+"\n" + "Duration : " + songDuration + "\n" + "Song Path : "
                        + songPath ,true);
                this.details_dialog.setCancelable(true);


            }
        });

    }

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 100) { 
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        // play selected song
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }


} // end

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
        String songAlbum2 = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songArtist");
        songAlbum.setText(songAlbum2);



        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

/**
 * 
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed
 * if repeat is ON play same song again
 * if shuffle is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if(isRepeat){
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}    

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

// ==== this is where I go to my home activity  

            Intent intent = new Intent(HirouMusic.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            super.onBackPressed();
```

return;
    }

}`

Comment: have you implemented the code?? so post here.........

Comment: On your onstop overide methods set ur media player object.stop();

Comment: Show some source code.

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this :**

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don`t want to pause the song, all I want is to save the state of the player activity when I click the back button and update the state of the player when I return to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        mp.pause();
        Intent intent = new Intent(HirouMusic.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        super.onBackPressed();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == 100) { 
    mp.start();
  }
}
```

in theory this would save the data of last song playing and play it when activity is created again, even if it uses pause. just try it and see

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Songig](https://github.com/mohammadmoradyar/songig) MusicPlayer library for android. Songig handle all your music playlist and let you to manage your list with many callbacks. you can bind many ui to songig for change them when needed. for example you can bind 2 seekbars to songig and songig will change progress of them in every update.